# How to save to managed object context in a background thread in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, core-data

I have an app which takes about a minute to set up, so when the user taps ‘Start New Game’ I want to show an activity spinner while data is loaded into Core Data.

I understand I have to do this on a background thread so I can update the UI on the main thread, but I don’t know how to save the managed context in the background thread. Here is what I have so far:

```
func startNewGame() {
  initiateProgressIndicator() // start the spinner and 'please wait' message

  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    self.coreDataStack.importDefaultData() // set up the database for the new game

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        stopProgressIndicator()

        // Transition to the next screen
        let vc: IntroViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IntroScreen") as! IntroViewController
        vc.rootVCReference = self
        vc.coreDataStack = self.coreDataStack
        self.present(vc, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
}
```

In importDefaultData() I need to save multiple times but it crashes when I try to do so. I understand now it's because I'm trying to access the main context from a background thread. Here is the basic structure of the function:

```
func importDefaultData() {
    // import data into Core Data here, code not shown for brevity

    saveContext()

    // import more data into Core Data here, code not shown for brevity

    saveContext()

    // import final data here

    saveContext()
}
```

From what I have read I think I need to create another managed object context for the background thread, but I am unclear on how to go about this and how to fit it into my current code. I also do not know how to make sure the data is saved correctly before I move on to the next screen. I have no experience with multithreading so any help would be appreciated.

Edit: regarding being marked as duplicate, the suggested topic is 8 years old and doesn't contain any answers. I was hoping for a more up to date answer with perhaps a brief code example in Swift.

Comment: The Apple Doc links in the linked post don't seem to be valid any longer

Comment: `let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)` `childContext.parent = parentContext`

Comment: Do all changes and saves within `context.performAndWait { }` or `context.perform { }`

Comment: For the Concept: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/coreDataOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010398-CH28-SW1

Comment: thanks @user1046037, your comments set me on the right path :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved this after reading the helpful comments from @user1046037 (thanks!) and researching how to use `context.perform { }` and `context.performAndWait { }`. I will post my code below in case it benefits anyone else, as I couldn't find any examples on SO in swift:

```
initiateProgressIndicator() // start the spinner and 'please wait' message

let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
childContext.parent = coreDataStack.managedContext

// Create a background task
childContext.perform {
  // Perform tasks in a background queue
  self.coreDataStack.importDefaultData(childContext: childContext) // set up the database for the new game

  do {
    // Saves the tasks done in the background to the child context
    try childContext.save()

    // Performs a task in the main queue and wait until this tasks finishes
    self.coreDataStack.managedContext.performAndWait {
        do {
            // Saves the data from the child to the main context
            try self.coreDataStack.managedContext.save()

            self.activitySpinner.stopAnimating()

            // Transition to the next screen
            let vc: IntroViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IntroScreen") as! IntroViewController
            vc.rootVCReference = self
            vc.coreDataStack = self.coreDataStack
            self.present(vc, animated:true, completion:nil)

        } catch {
            fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
        }
    }
  } catch {
    fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
  }
}
```

In my CoreDataStack class:

```
func importDefaultData(childContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
  // import data into Core Data here, code not shown for brevity

  saveChildContext(childContext: childContext)

  // import more data into Core Data here, code not shown for brevity

  saveChildContext(childContext: childContext)

  // import final data here

  saveChildContext(childContext: childContext)
}

func saveChildContext(childContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    guard childContext.hasChanges else {
        return
    }

    do {
        try childContext.save()
    } catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError
    }
}
```

If this approach is not best practise or anyone can see a way to improve it, I'd appreciate your thoughts. I should add that I found the following link very helpful: https://marcosantadev.com/coredata_crud_concurrency_swift_1

Comment: Why are you saving it 3 times ? After you save child context changes would be available in parent context but you need to save parent context for it to be written to the SQLite database file. If you don’t save your parent context and user kills your app then changes would be lost.

Comment: context.perform { } means that the code with in the { } would be executed in the thread suitable for that context. So when you are dealing with your child context which is in the private queue you should not directly do any UI updates (like stopping spinner) because UI stuff needs to be done on the main queue and the code block would be executed in the private queue. Use DispatchQueue.main.async { // UI stuff }

Comment: Difference between context.perform { } and context.performAndWait { } is that performAndWait would block the current thread till it has finished executing. So if you use perform the statements below the { } would be executed before the contents of { } is executed.

Comment: A cleaner approach would be to build Operations (formerly called NSOperation). That way you could chain together multiple operations and have dependencies. It requires you to read about it. It would take time to learn but it would be helpful in a real world app

Comment: Suppose if you make 10 inserts and 2 deletes and 1 update in a context, you don’t have to save 10 times. Saving once would save all inserts / updates / deletes. Reading the concept (in the link provided earlier) would help you understand better

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am aware I only need to save once, but I save multiple times because I do multiple fetches. For example, I create 'Country' entities from a plist, and later in the method I create 'Person' entities. To set the nationality attribute of Person, I must fetch the relevant 'Country'. I found that if I didn't save before attempting to fetch the 'Country', I got a "swift was mutated while being enumerated" error. Saving before the fetch fixed that.

Comment: I have since figured out how to update the UI and do indeed use DispatchQueue.main.async as you suggest. I will read up on Operations, thanks for the heads up.